# Dynamics CRM, create new or update (pie) charts with javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

Currently, I have a dashboard with different charts. But I need to create a new dashboard with new Charts with data populated from different entities that I gather with fetchingXML. When I get all data that I need I do the magic to transform and combine the data.

My wish is to create new several Dynamics charts and Dynamics table on custom Entity Form, where I can put all my new data that I got.

this need to be happening for Dynamics CRM 2013/2015 with javascript code.

Is there a way to do this or I need to use an outside library to do this?
Something like: "https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/1.0.0-beta.1/examples/multi-chart/"

Thank You!

Comment: CRM has pie charts, do you need something different ? Question doesn't explain what you need

Comment: I update the question, please review. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely something that has to be hand-crafted, CRM charts aren't really meant to manipulate displayed data.

You can create HTML Web Resources to include in the new dashboard, and then use plain JS or a library like `d3.js` (just to name the first that comes to mind) would allow you to build, from scratch, anything you like.